# How can the main thread wait until the new thread starts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, task

In an MVC controller I launch a new task like this:

```
Task.Run(() => <myFunction>)
```

It's a task that takes more than half an hour, so I don't want to wait for it: after launching it the program does a few things and sends the view back to the browser.

But the problem is that sometimes the task isn't executed. I think that maybe it is because the main thread stops before the second can be scheduled for execution. Can this be the real reason?

How can I do to wait till the new task begins its execution, so that I can then send the view to the client?

Comment: In an ASP.NET environment, long-running tasks should be started in some external container, like a Windows Service.  Pass the request to your Windows Service (via Remoting or WCR), and then return your View.

Comment: This is what I do in some cases: I call a WCF function hosted in a Windows service, and I call it as mentioned before (without wait or await). Sometimes the function isn't executed because the main thread stops before the new one can be launched by the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a task that takes more than half an hour,

2 mistakes here. Well, 1 at least. Choose.

- If it is a long running task, MARK IT AS SUCH. There is a hint (Tasks.LongRunning) that you can set in the factory.
- Use a thread.

Do not misdirect the task system. Just in general.

Now...

> But the problem is that sometimes the task isn't executed. I think that maybe it is 
>   because the main thread stops before the second can be scheduled for execution. Can this 
>   be the real reason

No. WHen Run returns, it returns and the task is scheduled. When it starts runing is left to the task scheduler - although that should be fast unless there is a large queue waiting in front. Want a determined start, either write your own scheduler or use a thread.

What is likely is that the whole asp.net process stops because it is not a container for long running tasks. If you want to schedule a significant time operation then use a container outside of asp.net to run your task - windows services, are made for exactly this. As are the windows task scheduler. Heck, with the right permissions you can just make the task an .exe and start it as a process. I would go with a windows service, though.

ASP.NET may at any time decide to recycle the whols appdomain / application pool running a website and restart it. For example when no request has been processed for a certain time (I think standard setup ois 20 minutes). Your task will then just be - stopped.

> How can I do to wait till the new task begins its execution,

- Put in a ManualResetEvent that the main thread waits for.
- Hand it into the task function.
- First thing the task dues is signal it so the main thread continues.

Does not bring anything though because it is fixing the wrong issue. A scheduled task DOES start - at one point when there is time. You just created with this a hanging asp.net worker thread which is a limited ressource to not fix an issue you think is there because of a bad analysis.

Comment: Thank you for this long explanation. However, I don't agree when you say that "A scheduled task DOES start": I have just made another test and I think that my analysis is correct, because when I do Task.run and immediately give the control back to the user interface, the task is run sometimes and sometimes not. If I just do Task.sleep(5000) after Task.run, the function is ALWAYS called. So it really seams that if the calling thread stops before the called one is scheduled, the second one doesn't start at all.

Comment: Absolutely not. Would be a super critical bug. When you find those 99% of the time the error is in your mirror as such a bug wuold not go unnoticed.

Comment: Well, anyway the solution of waiting 5 seconds completely solved my issue.